# Web Application Testing for .Net (WatiN Test Recorder)

Tags: .net, automated-tests, watin

I've been using WatiN as a testing tool for my current project. Besides the minor bugs with the Test Recorder, I've been able to use it and automate a lot of my tests in conjunction with NUnit. Anyone else out there with experience with different tools they might suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used:

> - [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)
> - [AutomatedQA TestComplete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/index.asp)

All of them have had their purpose and are very good tools.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Selenium before and hooked it into [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) and while it has it's quirks worked quite well.

Here are some useful links.

http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/

http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SIDE/Automating+Selenium+IDE+tests

http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2006/03/remote-web-app-testing-with-selenium.html

http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog_detail.jsp?rssItemId=97932

http://www.testearly.com/2006/10/04/selenium-using-selenium-ide-selenium-remote-control-and-ant/

Cheers
John

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a blog article [comparing Selenium and Visual Studio Automation Testing (Coded UI)](https://devermind.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/selenium-vs-coded-ui-my-perspective/) :

Answer (score 0):

WatiN is excellent.

I inherited [Mercury Quicktest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional) for functional testing a while back.  £30k for the licences and it was truly awful.  We never got the same results twice (running on the exact same application). Their support was terrible. It stored tests as collections of encrypted binaries in folders called useful things like Action1 and Action2, so we couldn't source control it properly.

No idea whether HP have improved it since they bought out Mercury, but why bother when WatiN is so good?

Comment: lol, Mercury is always inherited, never bought, management insists on using it because of the $$$$$ licenses.
In a previous job testers insisted on it 
because 'that was what they knew' and it's the same tool that they'd used for 10+ years to test desktop applications. 

I haven't seen WatIn, but selenium IDE can generate C# code, which can be run in the visual studio debugger within a unit test framework. 

Maintaining the test framework is where you'll spend a lot of your time, btw, so anything you can do to minimize that burden is great.

Answer (score 0):

I can also recommend WatiN. I've been using it exclusively for my web testing. I've even got it to play nice with VB.Net and HP/Mercury Quality Center(TestDirector).

Answer (score 0):

The best Open Source automation tool I have used are Selenium IDE and Selenium Remote Control. You can then run the scripts on IE, Firefox in both Mac and Windows.

If you prefer record-play, then download the Firefox add-on Selenium IDE and then record your scripts and run them.  You can very easily look at the scripts and figure out how to make minor edits.

If you want more power and flexibility of a full programming language, then consider Selenium Remote Control where I use Java and JUnit to drive the automation scripts. An easy way to started using RC is to use IDE  to record your scripts, save them as RC scripts and use JUnit framework to drive your test suite.

For more information, check out:

http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/
http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/