# what's the best Web testing tool have you found for C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, web-testing

I've been investigating a few of them.

What I have found so far that seems usable.

Windmill
Selenium 
Watin

Windmill looks like it has the basics (still not sure if I can write C# unit tests with it)

Watin seems awesome with Unit tests..

of the 3, it looks like Selenium is trying to be the most fully featured af the 3 (most recent version is today!)

any comments or suggestions?

Comment: C# web testing tool? C# alone cannot be used in web scripting. Only in things such as ASP.net, or silverlight etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Watin` has been voted the best so far. see following `Stackoverflow` posts

- [**What is the best way to do unit
  testing for ASP.NET 2.0 web pages
  (C#)?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-unit-testing-for-asp-web-pages-c#4386)
- [**Web Application Testing for .Net
  (WatiN Test Recorder)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015/web-application-testing-for-net-watin-test-recorder)
- [**What is the best way to unit test
  webforms apps ( ASP.NET )**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118531/what-is-the-best-way-to-unit-test-webforms-apps-asp-net)
- [**ASP.NET - How do you Unit Test
  WebControls?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151/asp-net-how-do-you-unit-test-webcontrols)
- [**Adding unit testing to an existing
  asp.net web forms application**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046816/adding-unit-testing-to-an-existing-asp-net-web-forms-application)

Answer (score 2):

Our QA team is using WatiN quite extensively on the project I'm working on currently.  WatiN has worked great for us so far - and we've actually hooked it up to our continuous integration server so the build fails if any of the unit tests that WatiN runs fail.  Kind of nice.  Further - there isn't an HTML element out there that you can't reference using WatiN, so even if the element you need to inspect doesn't have an ID or a class, you can always get to it some way or another.  Finally, WatiN executes tests quite quickly.  It really is very nice.

One other framework I will mention is [WebAii](http://www.artoftest.com/home.aspx). I've never used it personally, but I know some other people who like it quite alot.  I think the API is similar to WatiN.